# Not able apply filter when I select whole excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I have an excel sheet with macro-enabled when I select a column to apply the filter, it takes only 1653 cells, if I select all using shortcut key ctrl+a also it'll select only 1653 cells can you please help me.

Comment: Welcome! 1653 **cells**? Or **rows**? You tagged the question with #macros - is your code selecting the filter ranges? In this case, show this code, we will see together what is the error in it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> twice will select whole worksheet.